# How to create a curved road using <road> tag from SDF version 1.6 in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, sdformat, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This question and its answer provides a way to create a straight road in gazebo:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18565/how-to-make-a-simple-straight-road-in-gazebo/

How should I modify this to create a curved road in Gazebo?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19718/how-to-create-a-curved-road-using-%3Croad%3E-tag-from-sdf-version-1.6-in-gazebo?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can make it out of several small segments, for example:

```
 <road name="my_road">
   <width>7.34</width>
   <point>0 0 0</point>
   <point>5 2 0</point>
   <point>8 5 0</point>
   <point>10 10 0</point>
 </road>
```

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-06-15**:
Alright, thank you very much. Now I understood. Is there any way to define curvature to give a smooth curve?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-15**:
I don't think so, you can try to increase the resolution by placing more points close to each other.

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-06-15**:
Okay, thank you very much. I will write code in MATLAB to generate a set of points defining a curvature and use them in SDF file.

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-21**:
Does this apply to ign too? I tried that and it isn't showing up on my end